# Replacement of HeaderContributor.forCss() in wicket 6.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.6

I have code as shown below

```
public class ClasChangePassword extends OhterClass{
private Form frmChangePassword = null;

public ClasChangePassword(final PageParameters parameters) {
// some code.....
........
}

public void ChangePassword() {
frmChangePassword = new Form("cpform") {
protected void onSubmit() {
//some code...
}
};

frmChangePassword.add(pageFeedback);

        frmChangePassword.add(HeaderContributor.forJavaScript(ClasChangePassword.class, "keypass.js"));
        frmChangePassword.add(HeaderContributor.forCss(ClasChangePassword.class, "keypass.css"));

}
```

I replaced frmChangePassword.add(HeaderContributor.forCss(ClasChangePassword.class, "keypass.css")); code with below method, but not able to load css file

```
@Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forUrl("keypass.js"));
        response.render(CssHeaderItem.forUrl("keypass.css"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It should keep using the PackageResourceReferences:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(ClasChangePassword.class,  "keypass.js"));
    response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(ClasChangePassword.class,  "keypass.css"));
}
```